# Como enviar por metodo post, data de formulario via ajax para backend django?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, django-forms

Estoy intentado mandar unas respuesta de un formulario, donde ya teniendo la respuesta de la operación en el archivo `js`, busco la forma de enviar los datos y actualizarlos en la base de datos de mi `app` vía `ajax`, he visto muchos tutoriales y documentación, pero no doy con la solución, aquí le pongo mi código:

Archivo HTML:

```
{% extends "plantillas/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}  
{{ user.numero_empleado}}
<script src="{% static 'js/int.js'%}"></script>
<div><form method="POST" id="demo">
{% csrf_token %}

   <h6>Tipo de peticion:{{form.petit}}</h6>
   <h6>Razon:{{form.razon}}</h6>
   <h6>{{form.solicitudes_id}}</h6>
   <h6>Fecha inicio:{{form.periodo_init}}</h6>
   <h6>Fecha fin:{{form.periodo_fin}}</h6>
   <h6>Introduzca dias a tomar<input id="dias" type="number" name="dias_adicion"></h6>
   <h6>Introduzca horas a tomar<input id="horas" type="number" name="horas_adicion"></h6>
   <input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ user.d_pendientes }}">
   <input type="hidden" id="const_horas" name="h_pendientes" value="{{ user.h_pendientes }}">

Recuerde, que usted dispone de {{ user.d_pendientes }} dias y 
{{ user.h_pendientes }} horas a compensar <br>

<button type="submit" onclick="calculo()" class="boton">Guardar</button>
```

Donde de ese archivo, mando a llamar el `.js` con la siguiente operación:

```
   function calculo()

{

    var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias').value);
    var horas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('horas').value);
    var dias_base  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const_dias').value);
    var horas_base  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const_horas').value);

    dias_base -= dias;
    horas_base -= horas;

    alert(dias_base);
    alert(horas_base);
}     console.log(calculo);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#demo").calculo(function (_calculo) {
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/solit/",
       data: {
      'd_pendientes': $('#demo').val(), // from form
      'h_pendientes': $('#demo').val() // from form
    },
    success: function () {
      $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
    }
  });
  return false; //<---- move it here
});
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
def solit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        form = addiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('index')

    form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [

path("solit/", solit, name='solit'),

]
```

O sea, lo que busco es mandar a actualizar los campos de mi modelo haciendo la operación en el `frontend`, con `js` y el resultado de este mandarlo vía `ajax`, sin recargar la pagina a actualizar los datos del `user logeado`, cualquier ayuda o comentario, me seria de gran ayuda o si estoy haciendo algo man en uno de los archivos mencionados aquí en la pregunta y muchas gracias por su atención de antemano.

Comment: Actualmente cual es el error que te genera ?¡

Comment: int.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at int.js:17 @DiegoAvila

Comment: para que funcione este debes tener previamente incluido Jquery eso deberias hacerlo quiza en "base.html" por eso se genera dicho error.

Comment: @DiegoAvila eso no es, por que ya incorpore la libreria de jquery, y aun manda el mismo error en la consola. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza FormData así envías todo el formulario incluyendo en csrf_token

```
let data = new FormData($('#demo').get(0));
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/solit/",
   data: data, 
   success: function () {
      $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
   }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Retorna un `JsonResponse` con un

- True

ó

- False

```py
def solit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
       form = addiForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['guardo'] = True
       else:
            data['guardo'] = False
       return JsonResponse(data)
    form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

y después lo validas desde el front.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#demo").calculo(function (_calculo) {
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/solit/",
           data: {
          'd_pendientes': $('#demo').val(), // from form
          'h_pendientes': $('#demo').val() // from form
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.guardo){
              $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")  
            }else{
               //Mensaje de error ...
            }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: Muestra un ejemplo de como lo harias con mi codigo @Aprendiz por favor

Comment: @Jonathan yo no soy el autor de la respuesta